# How to change the color of tapped button in a specific row in ListView.itemBuilder

Tags: flutter, dart

I made StatefulWidget which generates a list by `ListView.itemBuilder`.

1. It has more than one rows.
2. Each row has 3 buttons (A, B, C)
3. I want to change the color of the button when it is tapped.

What has already been done

1. I can catch **the row number** of the tapped button and **which button** tapped out of these three buttons.
2. I am trying to change the color of button with `setState` function. For example: *When I tap the A button in the second row, it changes the color of **all** A buttons.*

I want to change the color of that A button only. How can I do this?

**This is my part of code:**

```
Expanded(
  flex: 8,
  child: Container(
    child: Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
      children: <Widget>[
        AppButton.buildAppButton(
          context,
          AppButtonType.BETSELECTION,
          matchList[index][4],
          kCategoryButtonDimensions,
          color: selectedOddIndex == kSelectedOddIndex[0]
              ? Colors.yellow
              : Colors.white,
          onPressed: () {
            setState(() {
              selectedOddIndex = 1;
              print(
                'satır ' +
                index.toString() +
                ' buton ' +
                selectedOddIndex.toString()
              );
            });
          },
        ),
        AppButton.buildAppButton(
          context,
          AppButtonType.BETSELECTION,
          matchList[index][5],
          kCategoryButtonDimensions,
          color: selectedOddIndex == kSelectedOddIndex[1]
              ? Colors.yellow
              : Colors.white,
          onPressed: () {
            setState(() {
              selectedOddIndex = 2;
              print(
                'satır ' +
                index.toString() +
                ' buton ' +
                selectedOddIndex.toString()
              );
            });
          },
        ),
        AppButton.buildAppButton(
          context,
          AppButtonType.BETSELECTION,
          matchList[index][6],
          kCategoryButtonDimensions,
          color: selectedOddIndex == kSelectedOddIndex[2]
              ? Colors.yellow
              : Colors.white,
          onPressed: () {
            setState(() {
              selectedOddIndex = 3;
              print(
                'satır ' +
                index.toString() +
                ' buton ' +
                selectedOddIndex.toString()
              );
            });
          },
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
),
```

Comment: what is this kSelectedOddIndex ? add more details. for this you definitely require List<List<int>> not List<int> only.

Comment: `onPressed ` you should save `index` and add it to condition like this `selectedOddIndex == kSelectedOddIndex[2] && index == tappedRowIndex
                                    ? Colors.yellow
                                    : Colors.white,`

Comment: const List<int> kSelectedOddIndex = [1, 2, 3]; I used it to understand which button tapped.

Comment: this works for me. Thank you selectedOddIndex == kSelectedOddIndex[2] && index == tappedRowIndex ? Colors.yellow : Colors.white Also thanks for the question format edit @VirenVVarasadiya